# DNS Warning while twilio sip call

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to implement twilio voice call using SIP.

I am following below blog for voice call. I have created two SIP endpoint and I want to do call between these two endpoints
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/making-phone-calls-using-twilio-sip.html

I am using Linphone and ABTo Android Softphone to test voice call. Setup of endpoints is done in softphones and it registered with twilio: `101@{domain}.sip.us1.twilio.com` & `102@{domain}.sip.us1.twilio.com` While I am going to call from one end point to other end point I am getting default programmable voice and then ringing call and call dismiss after ringing once.

I am getting this warning in twilio Debugger:

```
Warning - 13254
Dial->Sip: SIP URI DNS does not resolve or resolves to an non-public IP address

Msg "Host name DNS cannot be resolved."
ErrorCode   "13254"
invalidAddress  "{domain}.sip.us1.twilio"
LogLevel    "WARN"
```

How can I resolve this to do voice call using two sip endpoints?

Comment: it feels you missing the ".com" by looking at
`invalidAddress  "{domain}.sip.us1.twilio"`

Answer (score 0):

Try following a more recent blog post, it can be found below. I assume from above, you are replacing {domain} with the unique Twilio SIP Domain you created in your account.

[Registering a SIP Phone Directly to Twilio (and so much more...)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I got solution.

Comment: I am able to call now.. using above blog that I mention.. Now I want to test Call as you mentioned link .. but I am not able to make call using Twiml bin link. Can you please guide me? I am getting single ring and call drop.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to call. Previously I am using Linphone and ABTo Softphones. But as per below link while I am going to use Zoiper softphone I am able to do calling.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-registration#configure-your-sip-endpoint